# Get notification from Sinch when app killed

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, sinch

I have my own chat app with call video function using Sinch library. My problem is that when i kill my app, i do not receive any notifications to let the user know they have an incoming call. When the app is in background, everything works fine. So please show me how can i fix this, i'm using pushkit with voip certificate.

```
// delegate class sinch notification
    func managedPush(_ unused: SINManagedPush?, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: [AnyHashable : Any]?, forType pushType: String?) {

        if let dictionary = payload!["sin"]{
            let result_data = (dictionary as AnyObject) as! NSString
            if let data = result_data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                do {
                    json_data = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : Any])!
                } catch {
                    print("Something went wrong")
                }
            }
        }
        handleRemoteNotification(payload)
    }

    func handleRemoteNotification(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        if client != nil {
            let userId = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userId") as? String
            if userId != nil {
                initSinchClient(userId: userId!)
            }
        }

        result = client?.relayRemotePushNotification(userInfo)
        print(json_data)
        if (result?.isCall())! && (result?.call().isCallCanceled)! {
            self.presentMissedCallNotification(withRemoteUserId: result?.call().remoteUserId)
        }
    }

    func client(_ client: SINCallClient?, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall?) {
        //   Find MainViewController and present CallViewController from it.
        let currentUser:User? = {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            return realm.currentUser()
        }()
        let id = currentUser?.userDoctor?.userInfo?.id
        if let dict = result?.call().headers as? [String : String] {
            remoteId = dict["REMOTE_USER_ID"]
        }

        if let callId = remoteId {
            if id == Int(callId) {
                let getcallvideo_vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Chat", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "getcallvideo_vc") as! GetCallViewController
                var top: UIViewController? = window?.rootViewController
                while ((top?.presentedViewController) != nil) {
                    top = top?.presentedViewController
                }
                getcallvideo_vc.segueSinCall = call
                top?.present(getcallvideo_vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, localNotificationForIncomingCall call: SINCall!) -> SINLocalNotification! {
        let currentUser:User? = {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            return realm.currentUser()
        }()
        let id = currentUser?.userDoctor?.userInfo?.id
        if let dict = json_data["public_headers"] as? [String : String] {
            let remoteUserId = dict["REMOTE_USER_ID"]
            let remoteName = dict["USER_NAME_CALL"] as! String
            if id! == Int(remoteUserId!)! {
                let notification = SINLocalNotification()
                notification.alertBody = "Cuộc gọi đến từ \(remoteName)"
                notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
                return notification
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func presentMissedCallNotification(withRemoteUserId remoteUserId: String!) {
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        if application.applicationState == .inactive {
            let note = UILocalNotification()
            note.alertBody = "Cuộc gọi nhỡ từ \(remoteUserId!)"
            note.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            application.presentLocalNotificationNow(note)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add any code you have used to implement the library and links to questions you may have viewed to help you solve this issue. As it stands, your question doesn't currently provide enough insight to your problem.

Comment: thanks for your advice, i insert the code below